# How to convert json files stored in s3 to csv using glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have some json files stored in s3, and I need to convert them, at the folder folder they are, to csv format.

Currently I'm using glue to map them to athena, but, as I said, now I need to map them to csv.

Is it possible to use a Glue JOB to do that?

I trying to understand if a glue job can crawl into my s3 folder directories, converting all json files it finds to csv (as new files).

If not possible, is there any aws service that could help me do that?

EDIT1:

Here's the current code i'm trying to run

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data"]}, format = "json")
outputGDF = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = inputGDF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data"}, format = "csv")
```

The job runs with no error, but nothing seems to happen on s3 folder.
I'm supposing the code will get the json files from /dealer-data and convert to the same folder, as csv. I'm probably wrong.

EDIT2:

Ok, I almost made it work the way i needed.

The thing is, the create dynamic frame is only working for folders with files, not folders with subfolders with files.

```
import sys
import logging
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data/installations/3555/2019/2"]}, format = "json")

outputGDF = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = inputGDF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data/installations/3555/2019/2/bla.csv"}, format = "csv")
```

The above works, but only for that directory (../2)
Is there a way to read all files given a folder and subfolders?

Comment: is your data json stored month wise on S3? Like s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data/installations/3555/<year>/<month> ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `recurse` option to `True` for [S3 connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html):

```
inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {
        "paths": ["s3://agco-sa-dfs-dv/dealer-data/installations/3555/2019/2"],
        "recurse" : True
    }, 
    format = "json
)
```

Comment: Is it a correct answer? Does it work? Can anyone verify please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example how to convert from JSON to CSV. You can achieve it via visual ETL:

[image: Glue ETL JSOn-2-CSV]

Here is the generated code with parameters:

```
# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1698837830668 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://raw-data-rwt6y"]},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1698837830668",
)

# Script generated for node Explode Array Or Map Into Rows
ExplodeArrayOrMapIntoRows_node1698843098805 = AmazonS3_node1698837830668.gs_explode(
    colName="data", newCol="data"
)

# Script generated for node Flatten
Flatten_node1698843497504 = ExplodeArrayOrMapIntoRows_node1698843098805.gs_flatten()

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1698837833637 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=Flatten_node1698843497504,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://clean-zone-byef0c", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1698837833637",
)

job.commit()
```

Input JSON:

```
{"data":[{"p":34373.33,"s":"USD","t":1698819194578,"v":0.0012},{"p":34373.33,"s":"USD","t":1698819194578,"v":0.01303}]}
```

Output CSV:

```
data.p,data.s,data.t,data.v
34373.33,USD,1698819194578,0.0012
34373.33,USD,1698819194578,0.01303
```