# How to convert JSON to CSV file from s3 and save it in same s3 bucket using Glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Please help me with the coding part

I googled for the code, but it only shows with using lambda handler. My project requires use gluejob.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the answer for converting json to csv.

```
GlueContext glueContext = new GlueContext(Spark.getActiveSession())

val jsonDf = glueContext.getSource(
      connectionType = "s3",
      connectionOptions = JsonOptions(Map("paths" -&gt; "s3://:sourcePath/data.json")),
      format = "json",
      transformationContext = "jsonDf"
    )

val dataDf = jsonDf.toDF()
val csvRDD = dataDf.repartition(1).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
csvRDD.saveAsTextFile("s3://sourcePath/data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example how to convert from JSON to CSV. You can achieve it via visual ETL:

[image: Glue ETL JSOn-2-CSV]

Here is the generated code with parameters:

```
# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1698837830668 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://raw-data-rwt6y"]},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1698837830668",
)

# Script generated for node Explode Array Or Map Into Rows
ExplodeArrayOrMapIntoRows_node1698843098805 = AmazonS3_node1698837830668.gs_explode(
    colName="data", newCol="data"
)

# Script generated for node Flatten
Flatten_node1698843497504 = ExplodeArrayOrMapIntoRows_node1698843098805.gs_flatten()

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1698837833637 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=Flatten_node1698843497504,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://clean-zone-byef0c", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1698837833637",
)

job.commit()
```

Input JSON:

```
{"data":[{"p":34373.33,"s":"USD","t":1698819194578,"v":0.0012},{"p":34373.33,"s":"USD","t":1698819194578,"v":0.01303}]}
```

Output CSV:

```
data.p,data.s,data.t,data.v
34373.33,USD,1698819194578,0.0012
34373.33,USD,1698819194578,0.01303
```

I provided this answer for similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406007/3718363